# jQuery Horizontal Scrolling animation not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, scroll

I'm having trouble in jquery horizontal scroll animation. i'm rendering all of list data from database. it should visible only 4 item always. but on scroll its not showing hidden items and not showing 4 items. and also scroll stops after single scroll i want it to scroll until it reach end of list. how to solve please.

**[Style]**

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

#content {
    width: 500px;
}

.scroller {
    border: 1px solid #f00;
    height: 100px;
    width: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}

    .scroller li {
        float: left;
    }

    .scroller li {
        width: 24.5%;
        height: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        border: 1px solid #444;
    }

.item {
    background: green;
    position: relative;
}
```

**[html]**

```
<div id="content">
    <ul class="scroller">
        <li class="item">1</li>
        <li class="item">2</li>
        <li class="item">3</li>
        <li class="item">4</li>
        <li class="item">5</li>
        <li class="item">6</li>
    </ul>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="prev">&laquo;</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="next">&raquo;</a>
</div>
```

**[jquery]**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $item = $('li.item'),
    visible = 4,
    index = 0,
    endIndex = ($item.length / visible) - 1;
    $('#next').click(function () {
        if (index < endIndex) {
            index++;
            $item.animate({ 'left': '-=100px' });
        }
    });
    $('#prev').click(function () {
        if (index > 0) {
            index--;
            $item.animate({ 'left': '+=100px' });
        }
    });
});
```

[image]

Comment: Thanx! @Carsten Lovbo Andersen...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this snippet.
I changed your css and code just a bit

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
var $item = $('li.item'), 
visible = 4, 
index = 0,
endIndex = ( $item.length - visible ) -1; 
$('#content').css('width', visible * 100 + 'px');
$('#next').click(function(){
  if (index <= endIndex) {
    index++;
    $item.animate({'left':'-=100px'});
  }
});
$('#prev').click(function(){
    if (index > 0) {
      index--;
      $item.animate({'left':'+=100px'});
    }
  });
});
```

```css
* {margin:0;padding:0;list-style: none;}
#content{width:500px;}
.scroller{border:1px solid #f00;height:100px;width:auto;overflow:hidden; display: -webkit-box;}
.item{
  background:green;
  position:relative;
  float:left;
  width:98px;
  height:100%;
  text-align:center;
  border:1px solid #444;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
    <ul class="scroller">
        <li class="item">1</li>
        <li class="item">2</li>
        <li class="item">3</li>
        <li class="item">4</li>
        <li class="item">5</li>
        <li class="item">6</li>
        <li class="item">7</li>
        <li class="item">8</li>
        <li class="item">9</li>
        <li class="item">10</li>
    </ul>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="prev">&laquo;</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="next">&raquo;</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Gr8! Its scrolling perfectly but i have a question that is if i use item width as 25% instead of 100px its not properly positioning items how could i solve it? and i think var visible not work properly cause if i changed visible 3 it should render 3 item but its not doing that

Comment: @babymachinery I added the functionality that makes the `var visible` render that much items.. Try again.
As for the `width: 25%` it will be trickier this way because you will have to display 4 items each time. Think of it this way: what if you have a box of 5 visible items and you display 25% width per item.. that wouldn't work. Because 25% gives you 1 fourth of the div size and therefore it will render 4 items... You are better of with the fixed sizes, but if you must, you can dynamically calculate the visible items and change css dynamically.

Comment: Thanx! bro you worked hard for me. everything is working perfectly But facing another problem which is when i rendering items dynamically from database that case after 4 if i click next its not rendering 5,6 7... so on just blank. but if i test it manually then its gr8 whats my wrong? please

Comment: @babymachinery Sure man. You have to re render the item length each time you load from your database, for it to work.
So after you appended new results from the database to the HTML, run this line: `$item = $('li.item')`. If my anwswer helped you, I would appreciate if you select it as the answer for the post. Thanks

Comment: I dont understand where to put this line?

Comment: @babymachinery - Right after the line of code which adds new `<li>` to the HTML.

Comment: Sorry! its not working in my case... and I'm thinking another way. But truely it was great light weight easy solution.

Comment: @babymachinery Please update your question with the code so I can see what you have.

Comment: I already updated my code and also its output image. i'm using phalcon framework. all li data already loaded but onClick next or prev the output like given image. i'm not understanding what my wrong. here mention that im not using px for li, im using 25% of my total content div. thats it

Comment: Thank You So much! Solved my problem it was in my css... Cany plz tell me how to disabled next prev button when scroll end.